# time precedence and load constraint with add_indicator or add_if_then

Tags: python, cplex

I am implementing the precedence and load constraints of VRP(vehicle routing) in Python with Cplex. I try to use the add_indicator instead of big-M. But I do not know how to formulate md1.add_indicators(x[i,j,k], t[j,k]==t[i,k]+t[i,j], true_values=1) for i,j in A for k in K, to achieve the constraint  t[j,k]>= t[i,k]+travel_time[i,j]. It seems to me the add_indicator (or add_if_then) is only usable for each given number of i,j,k, such as md1.add_indicator(x[0,1,2], t[1,2]==t[0,2]+t[0,1], active_value=1).

Anyone could tell me how to deal with this? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that even simpler than indicators you could use logical constraints?

See

```
mdl.add(nbKindOfBuses==(nbbus40>=1)+(nbbus30>=1))
```

in

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0bab672a-5c2c-4235-bdf8-3837d4b32c46&ps=25